# How to integrate a Cytoscape canvas into a JavaFX Maven Application?

Tags: maven, javafx, cytoscape

I want to add graph visualization to a JavaFX application that I develop with Maven. However I can find no Maven artifacts since 2014 on https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.cytoscape?sort=newest and I don't know how to include Cytoscape into my JavaFX application.

Is such an integration actually possible and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Cytoscape is written for Swing so mixing it into JavaFX is probably not a great development path.  Much of the functionality is built into FX, so I'd recommend starting with native FX code.

I'd look into https://github.com/tesis-dynaware/graph-editor and https://jankoehnlein.github.io/FXDiagram

I've done some directed graph editors in JavaFX, the most recent of which was about biological pathways. https://github.com/AdamStuart/pathvisioFX